# asp mvc return viewmodel with html anchor

Tags: viewmodel, anchor, asp.net-mvc

I have a view for a blog post that return a view model with the post and the comments, and an anchor point at the end of the page where the comment form is.

After i submit the comment form, i want the POST method to return the View() but with the anchor point in the link

ie : **www.blog.com/article/my-first-article#comments**

right now i only have **www.blog.com/article/my-first-article** and in order to view the Validation Errors you must scroll down to the comment.

Any Ideas?

Thanks,
Alex

> ```
>     [HttpPost]
>     public ActionResult Index(ArticleWithCommentsViewModel vm)
>     {
>         if (ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             var newComm = new comment();
>             newComm.Name = vm.Name;
>             newComm.Email = vm.Email;
>             newComm.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
>             newComm.Comm = vm.Comment;
>             newComm.ArticleID = vm.ArticleToComment;
>
>             _db.comments.InsertOnSubmit(newComm);
>             _db.SubmitChanges();
>             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Article");
>         }
>
>         ArticleWithCommentsViewModel vm2 = new ArticleWithCommentsViewModel();
>         vm2.TheArticle = _db.Articles.ToList().Single(x => x.ArticleID == vm.ArticleToComment);
>         vm2.comments = _db.comments.ToList().Where(x => x.ArticleID == vm.ArticleToComment);
>
>         return View(vm2);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Think might be a little low tech but it might work:

```
return Redirect("www.blog.com/article/my-first-article#comments");
```